# How to send data with swagger (with url-encoded)

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a problem with the use of swagger. I'd like to send data with my swagger to test my routes but when I send the data the api receives nothing.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /clients/updatePassword:
 *  post:
 *      summary: Change le mot de passe d'un client en utilisant un email et un mot de passe.
 *      consumes:
 *        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 *      parameters:
 *        - in: formData
 *          name: email
 *          schema:
 *            type: string
 *          required: true
 *          description: E-mail du client à récupérer.
 *        - in: formData
 *          name: password
 *          schema:
 *            type: string
 *          required: true
 *          desription: Ancien mot de passe du client à récupérer.
 *        - in: formData
 *          name: newPassword
 *          schema:
 *            type: string
 *          required: true
 *          description: Nouveau mot de passe du client à récupérer. 
 *      responses:
 *        200:
 *          description: Mot de passe mis à jour avec succès.
 *        400:
 *          description: Requête invalide. Les paramètres email ou password sont manquants ou incorrects.
 *        401:
 *          description: Échec de l'authentification. Les informations d'identification sont incorrectes.
 *        500:
 *          description: Erreur serveur. Une erreur s'est produite lors de la connexion.
 */
router.post("/updatePassword", updatePassword);
```

I tried many things on the swagger docs but nothing work

Comment: Is your API definition `swagger: 2.0` or `openapi: 3.x.x`? Your annotations use a mix of both, which might be the cause the problem.

Comment: @Helen I have the API with openapi: 3.0.0, meabe i neeed to switch to the swagger: 2.0 ?

Comment: I just resolve the problem, thank you !! I just change the version and it worked